# Duda sobre un update usando sentencias preparadas

Tags: php, mysqli, sql, prepared-statements

```
    $username=$_POST["username"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $sex=$_POST["sex"];
    $description=$_POST["description"];
    $infoVisivility=$_POST["infoVisivility"];
```

La cosa es que recojo los datos de arriba desde un formulario para el usuario actualizar sus datos pero tengo cierta duda sobre esto, por ejemplo desde un archivo llamado `actualizar.php` está el formulario que mandará la información a `recoger_datos_actualizados.php` en `recoger_datos_actualizados.php` ya tengo la variable de sesión del usuario definida sin tener que recogerla del formulario ejemplo `$usuario=$_SESSION["id"]`.

Pues bien, ésta es mi duda: ¿a la hora de yo hacer la sentencia preparada es necesario hacer lo siguiente...?

```
  $username="UPDATE registro SET nombre=? WHERE id=? ";//el id hace referencia al la variable de session de el usuario
```

¿O puedo hacerlo directamente así?

```
 $username="UPDATE registro SET nombre=? WHERE id='$usuario' ";
```

Porque entiendo que la variable de sesión no viene desde el formulario si no que ya esté en `recoger_datos_actualizados.php`, ¿o de todas maneras hay que sanearla?

Espero me ayuden con esta simple duda, es que este mundo de sentencias preparadas es nuevo para mí, por lo tanto tengo algunas dudas. ¡Gracias de antemano,  comunidad!

Comment: la variable id, se esta generando de manera dinámica por parte del usuario dado lo cual también la debes proteger con una sentencia preparada usando los marcadores de posición como tu mismo lo indicas

Comment: vale gracias esa dudita me tenia blockeado por eso decidi recurrir a ustedes gracias @AlfredoPaz

Comment: Hay o puede haber trucos para modificar variables maliciosamente, por tanto, aunque no se trate de una variable que venga de un formulario, conviene que uses consultas preparadas con ellas, como bien ha dicho @AlfredoPaz. Yo tengo por norma no usar nunca una `$variable`  directamente en la consulta, venga de donde venga. Todas las `$variable` deben viajar aparte, o sea, en el *bind*, no en la consulta. Otra cosa sería un valor constante que sí se puede poner directamente sin ningún riesgo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Todo dato que esta llegando por parte del usuario, es decir que se esta generando de manera dinámica; debe ser tratado en una sentencia preparadam para proteger de posibles ataques de inyección SQL; dado lo cual debes dejarlo como:

```
//aquí la variable que tiene el valor de username
$username=$_POST["username"];
$usuario=$_SESSION["id"];
$consulta = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE registro SET nombre=? WHERE id=? ");
$consulta->bind_param("is", $usuario, $username);
$execute();
```

Por otro lado debes considerar que cuando se usan las setencias preparadas también es importante indicar el tipo de dato; por eso puse "is" para indicar que en el id espera un integer y en el username un string

Comment: gracias @Alfredo paz funciono bien !

Comment: Al final no sería $consulta->execute() o solo es cuando usamos PDO? me llamo la atención por que la el $ al principio como si estuvieras declarando una variable

Comment: @luis_am92 eso parece, $execute() no es una variable, es solo cosa de editar el final de la respuesta, aunque es muy correcta.

Comment: te falto ejecutar las consulta preparada
$consulta->$execute();